# detect catalina.out log path from a running tomcat on non-Windows

Tags: tomcat, logging, detect, absolute-path, catalina.out

I'm dealing with the following non-Windows OS types:

```
Oracle Linux
RedHat Linux
Ubuntu
Solaris Sparc
```

Given, the fact that if Tomcat process is running, what is the best solution to find out the absolute path of `catalina.out` (Tomcat logging)

`lsof` could be one solution but I'm not sure if it will be available on all the mentioned OS types.

I also looked at `<TOMCAT_HOME/conf/logging.properties` but could not get the desired absolute path. Also, I would prefer to get the information from a running process than som file value that can get overwritten.
Kindly suggest.